# css display table property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to organize a table-like setup with my webpage, i wanna move box number 7 here: http://puu.sh/gfekf/ac521ebc89.png
and move it below box number 5, what is the display:table property for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8p8a3f42/

```
<div class ="7 boxsubmit">
    <div class ="header">
            <h2>7.Input Type "submit"/"reset"</h2>
        </div>  
         <div class= "border">
            <div class ="spaceSeven">

            </div> 
          </div>
        </form> 

    </div>
```

---

```
   .1 { display:table-header-group;
        border-style: solid;
        margin-left:100px;

          } 
   .2 { display:table-header-group; 
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
   .3{ display:table-header-group; } 
   .4{ display::table-row-group} 
   .5{ display::table-row-group} 
   .6{ display::table-row-group} 
   .7{ display::table-row-group}
}
.boxsubmit{
    margin-top:70px;
    display:table-cell
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  I'm also not sure that this is the best way to go about it.  It seems like you're trying to use CSS to order table rows, which is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: I'm confused as well—why would you not use a float-based layout for this? Regardless, I did notice that you have `.1` etc as classes. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Display:table properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772739/css-displaytable-properties)